# How to read the last modified csv files from S3 bucket?

Tags: csv, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I come to you to find out if you have a pro tips for loading the latest csv files generated by a Glue job into an S3 bucket to load into jupyter notebook.

I use this command to load my csv from an S3 folder. Is there an option to select only files with the last modified csv files ?

```
df = sqlContext.read.csv(
    's3://path', 
    header=True, sep=","
)
```

Before I had a tendency to transform my dynamic dataframe into a classic dataframe to overwrite the old files generated by my Glue job.

This is not possible by generating a DyF

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use S3 boto3 api to get csv files with last modified date, then sort them, filter them and pass it to Glue or Spark read api.

Alternatively, you can use AWS S3 Inventory and query over athena: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html

There is Job Bookmark concept in Glue but it is for newly added files and not modified files.

Comment: @Rahul, it you wish to add snippet , please take care of 1000 limit on `list_objects_v2()` otherwise answer will not work for 1000+ files